# Excited diode allow flow opposite direction, possible?

Tags: led, current

I searched for some information regarding LED's and found out that they can only go one way because of the two metals inside of the LED have 2+/- electrons making it easy to go one way but difficult to go the other way. This got me thinking about valves. When valves are open you can also squeeze to the other side! So I was wondering if it is possible to excite an LED(through a laser beam or something similar) to allow current to flow to the opposite "allowed" direction.

Setup:

```
**+** = **+**
**|<|**= LED
**-** = **-**
--- = wire
LOAD=LOAD
```

I'm so clever. I know.

Laser beam shooting photons at LED

```
**+** --- **|<|** --- LOAD --- **-**
```

I tried googling this kind of information but it appears that no one has really thought about it. Or I'm a bad googler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, an LED will conduct in reverse if excited by an optical signal (of the right wavelength). This is basically just using an LED as a photodiode. Any reference on photodiodes will explain the underlying physics.

In fact, pretty much any diode will have this behavior. However, silicon diodes are typically packaged in opaque encapsulents to avoid the photoelectric effect producing significant reverse conduction. Also, photodiodes designed as photodiodes will be optimized to maximize the effect, while LEDs will not be.

Comment: Does this in turn mean I can make a cheap http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10636 by connecting 2 diodes to eachother putting normal connections to one to control the flow on the other diode(which goes reverse)?

Another tiny question, does the electrons going reverse also  suffer the same fate as going the "correct" direction? (Turning the LED to light/excited)

Comment: +1. There are some stories about glass-packaged diodes that pick up hum from fluorescent lamps or make circuits act in weird ways whenever the sun shines on them.

Comment: @HarrySvensson, on your first question, if you don't need the 8 A spec on the part you linked, can potentially find an optoisolator that does what you need for a price comparable to the cost of two LEDs (e.g., $0.50 or below for low current requirements). If you do need the 8 A spec, the LEDs required to do it will probably cost comparable to the $5 part. And a designed optocoupler/SSR will not be subject to problems from stray light, will be more efficient, etc.

Comment: @HarrySvensson, on your second question, in a photodiode, you don't turn electrons into light, you turn light into electrons. Yes, some (hopefully not very many) of the photo-generated electron-hole pairs will recombine and give a light output. But those electrons won't contribute to the current you are trying to generate when using the device this way.

Comment: What you can make is a two-way communications system. Look up "bidirectional LED TR2003" and read the document, for a fun project.